# BUG - Problem with content control in MAUI

Tags: maui

When I  use this code:
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
I get space the blue one at the header the blue one.

When I do this code no space at the header.

```
     public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, please try to edit it

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the app, i guess you want to hide the status bar.

If you want to hide the status bar of the app, you could try the following ways.

Android: Set the Fullscreen in MainActivity.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);      
}
```

iOS: Add the following key-value in `Info.plist`.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```